# Login system error with array and logout

Tags: php

I have put this in my code:

```
$rs=$mysqli->query('SELECT ip FROM allow_ip');
$allow = array();
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
{
    $allow[]=$row['ip'];
}
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow))
{
header("Location: ../../404.php");
exit();
}
```

and logout dont work with this!
if rework with this:

```
$allow= array("....","127.0.0.1","857...")
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow))
{
header("Location: ../../404.php");
exit();
}
```

work!!! why?
Logout is

```
    include_once '../protect/functions.php';
sec_session_start();

// Unset all session values 
$_SESSION = array();

// get session parameters 
$params = session_get_cookie_params();

// Delete the actual cookie. 
setcookie(session_name(),
        '', time() - 42000, 
        $params["path"], 
        $params["domain"], 
        $params["secure"], 
        $params["httponly"]);

// Destroy session 
session_destroy();
header('Location: ../../index.php');
```

why the array is the problem? or something else? and how i can find the solution?

Comment: You don't need this $i incrementor. Anyway, what does var_dump($allow) says from the first example

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "127.0.0.1" [1]=> string(1) "127.0.0.2" [2]=> string(12) "127.0.0.3" }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this (without using the index `$i`):

```
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
{
    $allow[]=$row['ip'];
}
```

`$allow` increments the index automatically

Comment: yes its my fault about $i++.... dont work again!
logout is:
`<?php
include_once '../protect/functions.php';
sec_session_start();
 
// Unset all session values 
$_SESSION = array();
 
// get session parameters 
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
 
// Delete the actual cookie. 
setcookie(session_name(),
        '', time() - 42000, 
        $params["path"], 
        $params["domain"], 
        $params["secure"], 
        $params["httponly"]);
 
// Destroy session 
session_destroy();
header('Location: ../../index.php');
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Well the code looks fine and given that you've stated the result of $allow is:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "127.0.0.1" [1]=> string(1) "127.0.0.2" [2]=> string(12) "127.0.0.3" }
```

then surely the answer is that the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] you are testing with doesn't match one of those values.

So what happens if you do:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]);
```

Comment: string(12) "@@.1@.@5.1@" NULL
EDIT: the problem is the logout dont work! if put this array!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say about the logout. Basically your REMOTE_ADDR doesn't seem to match one in $allow, so you will be redirected to 404.php - so your logout script will never execute as you would have been redirected. Unless you mean you have the logout script in the 404 page?

Comment: Ok listen....when i have this in my code:
$rs=$mysqli->query('SELECT ip FROM allow_ip');
$allow = array();
$i=0;
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
{
    $allow[$i]=$row['ip'];
    $i++;
}
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow))

logout dont work....
when i have this:
$allow= array("....","127.0.0.1","857...")
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow))

logout work!

Comment: But from the info you have supplied the only difference is $allow = `array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "127.0.0.1" [1]=> string(1) "127.0.0.2" [2]=> string(12) "127.0.0.3" }` in example one (from the DB query) and = `array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "...." [1]=> string(1) "127.0.0.1" [2]=> string(12) "857..." }` in example two. So it sounds like (assuming you don't want to be redirected to 404.php) $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is matching either "...." or "857..." - which don't exist in your database?

Comment: The script work perfect!!! all ip is example!! i have one login system and i add this code!! work perfect!!! BUT!! the logout.php dont work when i add this code:

$rs=$mysqli->query('SELECT ip FROM allow_ip');
$allow = array();
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
$allow[]=$row['ip'];
}
if(!in_array (...).......

and when i change the code to take ip from array and NO from db

$allow= array("127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1"); //ip is example
if(!in_array (...).......

the logout is WORK

Comment: Well if you haven't posted the exact results then how can you expect somone to be able to debug it for you? If it works when you take out the db call then this must be the problem. If you're running this from localhost - so $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = "127.0.0.1", you have an IP of "127.0.0.1" in your db, and $allow has been populated with an entry of "127.0.0.1" in the array, then there's no reason it would work different from using `$allow = array("....","127.0.0.1","857...")`. Without knowing the results I can only suggest you need to debug it yourself by dumping results at key points.

Answer (score 0):

To unset session datas, add this line too in your code :

```
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
```